# Switchery rendered wrong when triggering click after View is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, checkbox

I am using [switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) for my app checkboxes. In my code when a user opened a modal view, I read the saved checkbox state and update the checkboxes accordanly using

```
 $('.switchery:nth(3)').click();
```

So in the line above, the forth checkbox is toggled depends whether the saved state is true or false. This works without a problem.

The problem is that when I triggered the click dynamically after the view is shown, the rounded part of the switch appears at the right side of its container, instead at the inner right part as it should be.

When I clicked the switchery switch one the screen, it shows it correctly. Only when I run a code to toggle it after the view is shown, it shows incorrectly.

[image]

Looking at the CSS, I see that the `<small>` elements (the one that responsible to render the rounded element) has `left: 50px`; which causes it to render outside the switch boundaries (should be less). I think that the plugin calculated something wrong, but I have no idea how to solve it.

The switch rendres inside a phonegap app in KendoUI mobile view. It is wrapped around an `li` element

Comment: Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I will try to replicate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open switchery.js and replace *jack.offsetWidth* by 30 in *Switchery.prototype.setPosition* function.

This worked for me.